# Failing in building QT6 in YOCTO for IMX6Q

Tags: yocto, qt6, imx6

Hello I need to add QT6 to my yocto project but when I try to add qtbase to my local.conf: IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " qtbase"
I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'virtual/libgbm' (but /home/ieio/imx6QT/layers/meta-qt6/recipes-qt/qt6/qtbase_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
```

If I add PROVIDES += virtual/libgbm in meta-freescale/recipes-graphics/imx-gpu-viv/imx-gpu-viv-6.inc it fails to compile qtcore:

```
| ERROR: Feature "gbm": Forcing to "ON" breaks its condition:
|     gbm_FOUND
| Condition values dump:
|     gbm_FOUND = "FALSE"

| CMake Error at cmake/QtBuildInformation.cmake:194 (message):
|   Check the configuration messages for an error that has occurred.
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   cmake/QtBuildInformation.cmake:24 (qt_configure_print_summary)
|   cmake/QtBuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsConfig.cmake:568 (qt_print_feature_summary)
|   CMakeLists.txt:211 (qt_build_repo_end)
|
|
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Should I need to disable gbm? How can I do that?

Comment: Version of Yocto and the layers?

Comment: Yocto version is 4.2. QT version 6.6